# How to hide account details when user authorize to my application

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to integrate google drive with other application.
When user was asked to authorize, I see email Id on the authorization page.
How can I hide my details? or How can I change them?
Is Changing account details will effect my previous users info?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the upper-right corner of the consent screen, I don't think its possible since its a Google-managed page.

[image]

If you want to hide the "View your email address" authorization request, you'll have to remove its scope but this will greatly impact what your app does.